# Amadeus Hotel API Images

Tags: image, rest, amadeus

Is there any way for me to get Hotel's room images from your self-service API? Does the enterprise API support this functionality?

Based on your own documentation this type of information should be available through the following tag:

```
"media": [{
            "uri": "string"
          }]
```

but I'm not getting this tag using any of the search criteria that I'm currently testing with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

This question was related to the Hotel Search API v1 in the new version available (v2) the view=FULL is set by default.

---

You need to add:

> view=FULL

In your query to get the media.

For example:

> https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=LON&view=FULL

Note: we only have a few images in the test environment, most of the responses contain a fake image.

Comment: What about the version 3? I am trying with the test credentials and I don't see any image in the responses.