# How to get all images for a given hotel, using Self-Service Amadeus API?

Tags: image, amadeus

We tried in many ways without success.
Can only get one main picture. 
(There was a question posted before on this topic [Amadeus Hotel API Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595577/amadeus-hotel-api-images), however the answer doesn't work.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amadeus Hotel API Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595577/amadeus-hotel-api-images)

Answer (score 0):

You can get more images using the second endpoint of the [Hotel Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/hotel/api-doc/hotel-search/api-reference) and adding the parameter `&view=FULL_ALL_IMAGES`

For example:

> https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=BGMILBGB&adults=2&roomQuantity=1&paymentPolicy=NONE&view=FULL_ALL_IMAGES